# trading view widget customization issue

Tags: tradingview-api

i am using this widget from trading view. but i want to remove the logo from it, can you please help me guys?
https://in.tradingview.com/widget/technical-analysis/

i tried to use this java script code bellow.

```
document.querySelector('.label__link-dzbd7lyV').remove();
```

- remove their icon so it does not appear, and
- does not get redirected to the tradingview website.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think so we can remove the logo and stop from redirection.